# Streaming multicast on VLC over IPv6

Tags: vlc-media-player, ipv6, multicast

We are trying to send a **multicast** video stream using **VLC 2.2.1** on **IPv6** protocol between two computer - server and receiver. Both computers are connected via Ethernet cable from one network card to another. We were able to transmit a unicast stream on IPv6 by "listening" on the port in the receiver node. But when we try to "listen" on the multicast address it doesn't work.

This is the command we are running from the server's command line:

```
% vlc -vvv video1.xyz --ipv6 --sout udp:[ff08::1] --ttl 12
```

Where "ff08::1" is the address of the multicast group we want to transmit to. We are not sure though how to get the client to listen to this group address.

Anybody knows anything about it? Or can elaborate on the matter?

Comment: I know it’s been a few years, just some basic tricks: You should use a traffic sniffer like Wireshark to inspect incoming and outgoing traffic on both systems. Of particular interest are IGMP on IPv4 and and Multicast Listener Discovery (MLD) on IPv6. // Also, note that sometimes simply putting the network interface into promiscuous mode (as part of the sniffing) can “fix” problems. Don’t fall for that.

Answer (score 0):

Gui

Select File / Open Network Stream. To receive an UDP/RTP unicast stream sent to your system, you should select the Force IPv6 option (and possibly adjust the destination UDP port). To receive an UDP multicast stream, select the UDP/RTP Multicast option, and specify the multicast address to subscribe to inside square brackets.

Commandline

```
vlc -vvv --ipv6 rtp://@[ff08::1]:5004
```

or sometimes in linux/unix

```
vlc -vvv -rtp:@//\[ff08::1\]:5004
```

Where you can change the RTP to UDP if you are streaming over UDP.

https://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/ch12.html

Comment: tried that,
the client isn't receiving any stream at all.
there is no error, just black screen on the VLC.